# How do I reference a autonumber field in access vb and be able to use it for a calculation

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a auto number in a table that serves the purpose of a order id. I made a form to input line items for this order id into that table . I want a function that would allow me to click my "add to order button" and it would continue to use the same order id for every record until I complete the order. I tried the following in the `on_click` sub for my add record button.  `me.txt_Orderid = me.txt_OrderId - 1` but naturally that doesn't work. I am fairly new to access so the access vba is tripping me up. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using AutoNumber on a field if you are wanting to multiple records of it. Instead create a new field and use that for your orderid. When you create new orders youll want to grab the max of that field, then add one. see below...

```
On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec
If (MacroError <> 0) Then
    Beep
    MsgBox MacroError.Description, vbOKOnly, ""
End If

'This is where you assign new order numbers.
Me.OrderIDFormControl = (DMax("OrderIDField", "OrderTable") + 1)
```

This will acheive the same result, but is better. And you can have duplicates of it.

Once you fix your ID, then every time you add a OrderLine Item you just grab the id of the order, and assign it to the new records.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I have been trying to do.

Comment: No problem. I struggled with understanding the true purpose of the auto number field in the beginning, only to find out later i was doing it all wrong.  Auto Numbers should only ever be used for row identification. They shouldn't have any sort of meaning related to your data. Feel free to let me know if you have any other questions. Access is a bit challenging in the beginning all by yourself!

Answer (score 0):

There would be two tables tblOrder which will be master table for Orders. You can use OrderID as autonumber in this table. And second table would be tblOrderItems , this would be the detail table having duplicate values of OrderID for more than one Order Items.

Create a form frmOrder that binds to tblOrder, create another form that binds to tblOderItem. Now open the Order form in design mode, press F11 to see other forms in database, drag and drop frmOrderItem being create. Now this form will be  a subform inside main Order form. 
The sub-form property,  set Master field, Child field property . You will be asked to set related fields, it would be OrderID from both the tables/forms.

You can use this form without need to code to get OrderID when inserting data to tblOrderItem. Access picks up value for you and adds.

Still if you want to have OrderID in your code for any reason or coding a unbound form/subform. You can get the value of OrderID from frmOrder form. when referring this tbOrderID text box control anywhere in the code of frmOrder, you can just use tbOrderID.value , but if you want to refer the text box in subform, remember to refer it with form name or get from Parent property of sub form for e.g. Forms![frmOrder].tbOrderID.value in case you want to use with Parent e.g. Me.Parent.form.tbOrderID.value

Comment: Thanks for all your help.